# Counting pair in a poker hand - counting confusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, poker

I want to be good enough to do math competitions, and one of the main topics in them is always combinatorics. So I'm going through a combinatorics book, "A Walk through Combinatorics."

The confusion I have is with the following problem:

Find the prob that a poker hand has a pair( and nothing better than a pair).

My attempt:
We know that a poker hand has five cards from a deck of 52 cards. Each card is equally likely so the total combinations is:  $${52} \choose 5$$

The number of hands that contain only a pair and nothing better than a pair are:
$${{13} \choose {4}} * {{4} \choose {2}}* {{4} \choose {1}}^3$$

There are 13 cards of each card. We choose 4 the 13 values. Then from one of the groups we want a pair, and from the remaining group we want a single.

So, the probability I got was:

$$\frac {{{13} \choose {4}} * {{4} \choose {2}}* {{4} \choose {1}}^3}{{52} \choose 5}$$.

However, according to  the answers:

The correct probability should be :
$\frac {{{13} \choose {1}} *{{12} \choose {3}} * {{4} \choose {2}}* {{4} \choose {1}}^3} {{52} \choose 5}$

Where is my logic flawed? Where am I going wrong? Am I double counting somewhere? I think my answer produces a smaller probability so am I undercounting?

Comment: There are $4$ ways to choose the rank that will have the pair.  Otherwise, you did fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is your ${13 \choose 4}$ versus their ${13 \choose 1} {12 \choose 3}$ (your ${4 \choose 2}$ and ${4 \choose 1}$ factors are correct).  You're choosing the four of 13 ranks in the hand, but not specifying which rank has the pair.  They choose the rank for the pair with ${13 \choose 1}$ and then the three other ranks with ${12 \choose 3}$.

Comment: Why might what I'm doing be logically wrong? I don't see why not specifying which rank gets the double is wrong to do.

Comment: ${13 \choose 1} {12 \choose 3} = 2860$ while ${13 \choose 4} = 715$, different by a factor of 4.  You're missing the choice of which of the 4 ranks will have the pair.  If you prefer, you could keep ${13 \choose 4}$ and then include another ${4 \choose 1}$ factor to select which rank gets the pair (as @saulsplatz suggested).  But it's also good to understand why their answer works, too.

Comment: AHHHHHHHH!!! That makes so much sense! Thank you a BUNCH!

Answer (score 2):

The number of hands containing only a pair can be so calculated

1) Select the pair: AA, 22,...,KK and you have $13$ choices

2) select the suits of the pair: you have $\binom{4}{2}=6$ choices

3) select the three single cards: $\binom{12}{3}$ choices

4) for each single triplet you have to choice the suits (the suits can be repeated) : $4^3$ choices

....multiply all and get the number of choices containing ONLY one pair

$$13\times\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{12}{3}\times 4^3=1,098,240$$

Comment: Why is my why of approaching the problem wrong? What I did was: 
1. Of the 13 ranks, choose 4 of them 
2. Since each rank has four cards, choose 2 of the four which will serve as the double
3. Now choose the remaining 3 singles from their respective group of 4